# Twitter Oauth Delphi 7 home_timeline getting 401 unauthorized

Tags: delphi, oauth, delphi-7

I am using Oauth for Delphi from ChuckBeasley.com

I am able to get a request token, then call with my callback url and put in my credentials.

I then get redirected correctly to my callback url in a TEmbeddedWB component.
I then get an access token (at least I believe I am) since screen_name and user_id come back in the response.

When I try and pull my home_timeline it gives me a 401 unauthorized as a response.

What can I be doing wrong?

Thanks
David

Comment: Fiddler helped me somewhat.  Looks like I have an incorrect signature? Although, I am following the class and example laid out for this Oauth for Delphi.  Any one else utilizing it out there?

Answer (score 1):

try my implementation, it doesn't use the OAuth library, but my own from scratch

http://eden.fm/2011/02/27/twitter-library-for-delphi/

Answer (score 0):

You're also welcome to use my open-source Twitter component (TTwitter for Delphi) which is being developed as part of a "complete" suite of Social Networking components (if there is such a thing as "Complete" in terms of social networking). You can find it at: http://www.simonjstuart.com/delphi-stuff/ttwitter/

It's using the ChuckBeasley OAuth library, only I have fixed it (so it ACTUALLY WORKS). In the very least you'll be able to reverse engineer my component to suit your needs. It's an open beta (far from complete at its current released stage) but it handles timelines perfectly (including unicode characters).

Enjoy and good luck!